# C - How can I send a proper HEAD request to a website?

Tags: c

I am trying to send a HEAD request to a website's root document. Here is my code:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int csd;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct hostent *server_host;
    int server_len;
    int string_size;
    short server_port;
    char req_buffer[BUF_LEN];
    char temp_buffer[BUF_LEN];
    char receiveBuffer[BUF_LEN];
    char resource_buffer[BUF_LEN];
    int t;

    if(argc!=2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s website \n",argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    server_host=gethostbyname(argv[1]); //resolve hostname
    if (server_host == NULL)
    {
        herror("While calling gethostbyname()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    csd=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //create socket
    if(csd<0)
    {
        perror("While calling socket()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    memcpy(&server.sin_addr, server_host->h_addr_list[0], server_host->h_length);
    server.sin_port = htons(80);
    server_len=sizeof(server);
    t = connect(csd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, server_len);
    if (t<0)
    {
        perror("while connecting()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("connected to server\n\n");
    }

    printf("input resource, with format'/(resource name)'\n"); //request for resource (for example /index.html)
    scanf("%s", temp_buffer);
    printf("retreiving HEAD...\n\n");

    sprintf(temp_buffer, "HEAD %s HTTP/1.0\r\n", resource_buffer);
    strcpy(req_buffer, temp_buffer);
    sprintf(temp_buffer, "HOST: %s\r\n", server_host);
    strcat(req_buffer, temp_buffer);

    sprintf(temp_buffer, "\r\n");
    strcat(req_buffer, temp_buffer);

    write(csd, req_buffer, strlen(req_buffer));

    read(csd, receiveBuffer, BUF_LEN);

    printf(receiveBuffer);
}
```

So far I have not been successful I am only getting bad requests. I tested using the website: man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html and man7.org/mtk/index.html

Comment: At least HTTP 1.0 doesn't have a host header. You might want to go for 1.1

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Hey I modified my code but I am still getting bad requests.

Comment: Could you post the exact request you're sending to the server?

Comment: Not to mention you're sending a struct as a host header hostname. That kinda makes things broken, as you could've seen if you printed out the request.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen You were right I was sending "HEAD HEAD HEAD H HTTP/1.1. Host: -a~

Answer (score 1):

First you're using `host` header which doesn't exist on HTTP 1.0, you need to use 1.1. Also add `connection: close` to make sure keepalive isn't used.

The main issue is most likely that you use `server_host` in the host header. It is not a string, it is a struct, so it will output garbage into your request.

A simple debugging session or just outputting the request you send out would show this error.